# Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$.

Tags: limits, continuity

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $a$ and that $f(a)>0$. Prove that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in some interval containing $a$.

We are supposed to write a formal proof, and I am struggling with how to prove this statement.

Comment: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, 
and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them 
give their answers at the right level. As it is, since your question is phrased as an isolated problem without
any further information or context, it does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may 
attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, consider editting the question to add more content.

Answer (score 1):

Corresponding to $\epsilon=\frac{f(a)}{2}>0$, we can find $\delta>0$ such that for any $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$, we have
$$|f(x)-f(a)|<\frac{f(a)}{2}.$$ This means that if $x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta)$ then
$$-\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)-f(a)<\frac{f(a)}{2}.$$ Hence, for all $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$, we have
$$-\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)-f(a)$$ that is, $$f(x)>-\frac{f(a)}{2}+f(a)=\frac{f(a)}{2}>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Since $f$ is continuous at $a$ for any $\epsilon\gt 0$ we can find $\delta\gt 0$ such that $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)\implies f(a)-\epsilon\lt f(x)\lt f(a)+\epsilon.$

Again since you are given that $f(a)\gt 0,$ choose **$\epsilon\gt 0$** to be something that makes $f(a)-\epsilon\ge 0$